# is it possible to preload html before displaying on webview

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview

I have searched whole internet and couldn't find the solution so decided to ask expert that is it even possible.

I have a Blog for which I am developing iOS app but it takes too much time loading the content.

So is it possible to pre load html (not images) of all articles before user opens the article, just like FB instant articles. FB instant articles are preloaded and cached and when user opens it then it opens in a flash except images, which download when user opens it.

Currently I am using uiwebview which I am planing to replace with wkwebview.

Thanks for help in advance.

call to cache

```
CachedArticles.shared.cacheArticles(self.articles) { success 
    print("cache creation finished, success: \(success)")
}
```

call to webview

```
tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
let webVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"NewsReaderViewController") as! NewsReaderViewController
webVC.article = self.articles?[indexPath.row]
navigationController?.pushViewController(webVC, animated: true)
```

cache class

```
import UIKit

class CachedArticles: NSObject {

static let shared: CachedArticles = CachedArticles()

let cachePath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.cachesDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first!

func cacheArticles(_ articles: [ArticalClass]?, completion: @escaping (Bool)->() ) {

    guard let articles = articles else { return }

    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
        }

        var success = true

        for article in articles {
            guard let path = article.url, let url = URL(string: path), self.webArchive(forHeadline: article.headline!.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")) == nil else { continue }

            print("caching article: \(article)")
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                let url = self.cacheFileURL(forHeadline: article.headline!)
                STWebArchiver().archiveHTMLData(data, textEncoding: "UTF-8", baseURL: url, completionBlock: { data in
                    (data! as NSData).write(toFile: url.path, atomically: true)
                })
            } catch let error {
                success = false
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
            completion(success)
        }
    }
}

func webArchive(forHeadline: String?) -> URL? {
    let url = cacheFileURL(forHeadline: forHeadline!)
    return FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path) ? url : nil
}

private func cacheFileURL(forHeadline: String) -> URL {
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: self.cachePath).appendingPathComponent(forHeadline.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")+".webarchive")
    return url
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch the html file by a HTTP request at the pre-view and save it to cache, and check if it's in cache when you really entry it.

=================================================

4.24 updated
there are two factors

firstly, I don't know how the 'articles' array generated, and if it contain the src url.

secondly, I have reviewed the STWebArchiver code and I found it:

```
- (void)archiveHTMLData:(NSData *)aData
       textEncoding:(NSString *)anEncoding
            baseURL:(NSURL *)anURL
    completionBlock:(void (^)(NSData *))completion {
htmlDocPtr doc = htmlParseDoc((xmlChar *)[aData bytes], [anEncoding UTF8String]);
NSArray *pathsForImagesAndScripts = [self valueForAttributeName:@"src" withEvaluatingXPath:@"//script[@src]|//img[@src]" inDocument:doc];
NSArray *pathsForStylesheets = [self valueForAttributeName:@"href" withEvaluatingXPath:@"//link[@rel='stylesheet'][@href]" inDocument:doc];
NSArray *resourcesPaths = [pathsForImagesAndScripts arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:pathsForStylesheets];
NSArray *resourceUrls = [self absoluteURLsForPaths:resourcesPaths baseURL:anURL];
dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("Downloads", 0), ^{
    NSMutableDictionary *resources = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    dispatch_apply([resourceUrls count], dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^(size_t i) {
        NSURL *url = [resourceUrls objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];
        BOOL unfetched = NO;
        @synchronized (resources) {
            unfetched = ![resources objectForKey:urlString];
            if (unfetched) {
                [resources setObject:[NSNull null] forKey:urlString];
            }
        }
        if (unfetched) {
            NSURLResponse *response;
            NSError *error;
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                                 returningResponse:&response
                                                             error:&error];
            NSMutableDictionary *resourceArchive = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                    urlString, @"WebResourceURL",
                                                    [response MIMEType], @"WebResourceMIMEType",
                                                    data, @"WebResourceData", nil];
            if ([response textEncodingName]) {
                [resourceArchive setObject:[response textEncodingName] forKey:@"WebResourceTextEncodingName"];
            }
            @synchronized (resources) {
                [resources setObject:resourceArchive forKey:urlString];
            }
        }
    });
    NSMutableDictionary *archiveSource = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[resources allValues] forKey:@"WebSubresources"];
    NSMutableDictionary *mainResource = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [mainResource setObject:aData forKey:@"WebResourceData"];
    [mainResource setObject:@"" forKey:@"WebResourceFrameName"];
    [mainResource setObject:@"text/html" forKey:@"WebResourceMIMEType"];
    [mainResource setObject:anEncoding forKey:@"WebResourceTextEncodingName"];
    [mainResource setObject:[anURL absoluteString] forKey:@"WebResourceURL"];
    [archiveSource setObject:mainResource forKey:@"WebMainResource"];
    NSData *webArchive = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:archiveSource
                                                                    format:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0
                                                          errorDescription:NULL];
    completion(webArchive);
});
xmlFreeDoc(doc);
}
```

which means that STWebArchiver cache not only the pure HTML file but also the resource requested.

Comment: I tired that but it's fetching/downloading images as well which is very data consuming.

Comment: Thanks a ton bro, I will review it see if it helps.  And articles content src url also I am avoiding image cache as it can eat a lot of user's bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a "greedy" webview approach by creating them before hand before they are even added to view hierarchy and starting their request. That assumes each webview instance would display one page that doesn't navigate to other html pages. `appDidFinishLaunching` would be a place to do the setup.

Comment: unfortunately it may navigate to other html pages.